# Ubuntu 20 not coming up after hibernating or sleep mode

Tags: ubuntu, boot, laptop, power, hp-laptop

my ubuntu 20.x.x doesn't come up when it sleeps or hibernate and when i power off, the display goes off but my i can still hear my hard-drive spining (the indicator by the side of the laptop is still on) which makes it hot after a while.

i have tried updating (not upgrading) the the OS and softwares.

what might the issue be?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.